# Hive select a particular string from a json row

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-athena

Im trying to analyze AWS cloud trail logs  in Athena, for that If I select security group add **inbound rules event** it returns the below string in *elements column*.

```
{"groupId":"sg-XXXX","ipPermissions":{"items":[{"ipProtocol":"tcp","fromPort":22,"toPort":22,"groups":{},"ipRanges":{"items":[{"cidrIp":"0.0.0.0/0"}]},"prefixListIds":{}}]}}
```

But I need `groupId` alone from that json results. So how can I get that ?

> Note: The tables is an external table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select json_extract_scalar('{"groupId":"sg-XXXX","ipPermissions":{"items":[{"ipProtocol":"tcp","fromPort":22,"toPort":22,"groups":{},"ipRanges":{"items":[{"cidrIp":"0.0.0.0/0"}]},"prefixListIds":{}}]}}','$.groupId');
OK
sg-XXXX
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 
In AWS Athena `get_json_object ` is not registered :(

Comment: Please try `json_extract_scalar` instead