# Hive lateral view not working AWS Athena

Tags: arrays, json, amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-athena

Im working on a process of [AWS Cloudtrail log analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42877874/hive-select-a-particular-string-from-a-json-row), Im getting stuck in extract JSON from a row,

This is my table definition.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE cloudtrail_logs (
eventversion STRING,
eventName STRING,
awsRegion STRING,
requestParameters STRING,
elements STRING  ,
additionalEventData STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.amazon.emr.hive.serde.CloudTrailSerde'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'com.amazon.emr.cloudtrail.CloudTrailInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3://XXXXXX/CloudTrail'
```

If I run `select elements from cl1 limit 1` it returns this result.

```
{"groupId":"sg-XXXX","ipPermissions":{"items":[{"ipProtocol":"tcp","fromPort":22,"toPort":22,"groups":{},"ipRanges":{"items":[{"cidrIp":"0.0.0.0/0"}]},"prefixListIds":{}}]}}
```

I need to show this result as virtual columns like,

```
| groupId | ipProtocol | fromPort | toPort| ipRanges.items.cidrIp|
|---------|------------|--------- | ------|-----------------------------|
| -1      | 0          |          |       |                             |
```

Im using AWS Athena and I tried Lateral view and get_json_object is not working in AWS.

> its an external table

Comment: Please give a better data sample where "items" contain multiple elements

Comment: Question updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  json_extract_scalar(i.item,'$.ipProtocol')  as ipProtocol
       ,json_extract_scalar(i.item,'$.fromPort')    as fromPort
       ,json_extract_scalar(i.item,'$.toPort')      as toPort

from    cloudtrail_logs
        cross join unnest (cast(json_extract(elements,'$.ipPermissions.items') 
            as array(json))) as i (item)
;
```

---

```
 ipProtocol | fromPort | toPort
------------+----------+--------
 "tcp"      | 22       | 22
```

Comment: select  json_extract_scalar(u.j,'$.ipProtocol') as ipProtocol
       ,json_extract_scalar(u.j,'$.fromPort')   as fromPort
       ,json_extract_scalar(u.j,'$.toPort')     as toPort

from  cl1   cross join unnest (json_extract(requestparameters,'$.ipPermissions.items')) as u(j);

I tried this, it throws 


INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Cannot unnest type: json

Comment: I thought the column is array of jsons. Is it a json containning array? Please add the table definition (at least for the relevant column) to your post.

Comment: Yes, 

its a part of my previous question[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42877874/hive-select-a-particular-string-from-a-json-row, You answered for that.                               So the main goal is I need to extract the json row into columns.
                                                                                                                                {"groupId":"sg-XXXX","ipPermissions":{"items":[{"ipProtocol":"tcp","fromPort":22,"toPort":22,"groups":{},"ipRanges":{"items":[{"cidrIp":"0.0.0.0/0"}]},"prefixListIds":{}}]}}